# How to exclude a character in Regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have this Regex expression

```
UriPatternToMatch= new Regex(@"(href|src)=""[\d\w\/:#@%;$\(\)~_\?\+\-=\\\.&]*", 
RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

This is working fine to pickup all URLS including http,ftp and others , but it picks up text within `"&lt"` special characters as URL too

for example it will wrongly pick up the text below as a URL too ( adding a photo instead of text below)

[image: snapshot]

I believe something like ^&lt is what is needed , but where do I add it ?

Thanks

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind. You can find details at regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use negative lookahead like this:

```
(?!.*?&lt;)
```

Comment: do I just put it afterwards...like this (href|src)=""[\d\w\/:#@%;$\(\)~_\?\+\-=\\\.&]*(?!.*?&lt;)